# How do I fullscreen browser content in Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fullscreen, web-browser

I realize that one can run apps in a macOS full screen mode, but sometimes I really want the webpage itself to take up the full screen real estate. And ideally, that would not require me to open such a page in a different browser.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

View → Enter Full Screen (⌃⌘F), then View → Always show toolbar in full screen (⇧⌘F).